# Can I use app.use inside app.get with different paths

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web, backend

I have this bit of code that takes the last 10 url requests in the path '/img' and put it in an array and then I have two conditions. One if the array length is already 10 then delete the last index and add the new one to the beggining of the list. And other if the index of url is already in the array delete that one so I do not have any repeated url in this list. Here is the code:

```
let recentPaths = [];

app.use('/img', (req, res, next) => {
const index = recentPaths.indexOf(req.originalUrl);
if (recentPaths.length === 10) {
recentPaths.pop();
}
if (index !== -1) {
  recentPaths.splice(index, 1);
}
recentPaths.unshift(req.originalUrl);
next();
});
```

and then I have this get function which is where I want to have the data from that array. Here is the code:

```
app.get('/stats/paths/recent' ,sendRecentPaths);
async function sendRecentPaths(req, res) {
  res.json(recentPaths);
}
```

It is working but my question is, can I do that first block of code inside this get function?
I mean, can I use the app.use() inside app.get() ? Because I want the request from the path '/img' to be sent in an array to the path '/stats/paths/recent'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's incorrect to put `app.use` inside `app.get` because middleware should be defined once, not on every request.

If the intention is to exchange data between middlewares that are executed within same request, they should communicate through [response object](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.locals):

> res.locals
>
> An object that contains response local variables scoped to the
>   request, and therefore available only to the view(s) rendered during
>   that request / response cycle (if any). Otherwise, this property is
>   identical to app.locals.
>
> This property is useful for exposing request-level information such as
>   the request path name, authenticated user, user settings, and so on.

I.e. an array could be assigned to `res.locals.recentPaths` middleware and be read in another middleware. The problem with this case is that `/img` and `/stats/paths/recent` middlewares aren't executed within same request.

It's incorrect to store data to `recentPaths` variable because it persists between requests and is global for all users. If data should persist between requests and be specific to users, this should involve session management, a better place to store data is a database, not a variable.